# How to create a link to open my app if its installed

Tags: android, ios

I have this issue,
How can i create a link to open my app if it's installed if not then go to app store
Could you please help me?
thank you

Comment: [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive) might help

Comment: This is called DeepLinks. you need to make a code change in your app in order to handle it.

Comment: i just have the apk installed so i cant modify anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use several things Firbase Dynamic links is one of the best you can check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

Also, you can use branch.io  check [here](https://branch.io).(More specifically deep linking [here](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/))

Comment: thank you, is another way to do it without using firebase or branch, javascript or something, because i just have the apk installed so i cant modify anything

Comment: In android you can handle specific link and open the app if the app is installed, but again you need to rebuild the app.